# SQL select according to hierarchy

Tags: sql, select

from the table as below I need to select
one record for each GEID according o hierarchy:
-- minimum CCSHierarchy , if there is more than one record
-- minimum RegistrationDate , if there is more than one record
-- minimum RegFromHierarchy , if there is more then one record
-- minimum EnrMandHierarchy

| GEID | CCSHierarchy | RegistrationDate | RegFromHierarchy | EnrMandHierarchy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9D0054560 | 1 | 2020-05-13 | 2 | 2 |
| 9D0054560 | 1 | 2020-05-13 | 1 | 1 |
| -------- | ------------- | ------------------ | ------------------ | ---------------- |
| 9D0131758 | 2 | 2020-02-28 | 2 | 2 |
| 9D0131758 | 2 | 2020-08-25 | 1 | 2 |
| -------- | ------------- | ------------------ | ------------------ | ---------------- |
| 9D10057241 | 4 | 2019-04-19 | 2 | 2 |
| 9D10057241 | 3 | 2019-11-06 | 1 | 2 |

I tried this query, but the hierarchy is not kept

```
 with data as 
(----
 ) 
  select 
  d.GEID
, d.ClassCode
, min(d.CCSHierarchy) MINCCSHierarchy
, MIN (d.RegistrationDate) MINRegistrationDate
, min (d.RegFromHierarchy) MINRegFromHierarchy
, min (d.EnrMandHierarchy) MINEnrMandHierarchy

 from data d
 group by d.ClassCode, d.GEID
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results.  In this case it would be helpful also to provide the results that you got and an explanation of why that's wrong.  (We don't intuitively understand the hierarchy you have in mind...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select d.*
from (select d.*,
             row_number() over (partition by geid order by CCSHierarchy,    RegistrationDate, RegFromHierarchy, EnrMandHierarchy) as seqnum
      from data d
     ) d
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: perfect, thank you! I only added sorting order and it works :)